# ¿Cómo solucionar el fatal error Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Estoy realizando una función para editar registros de mi base de datos, pero al intentar editar alguno me marca este error

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your
> SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
> version for the right syntax to use near 'subclase_ s marca_ m ...' at
> line 4 in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\papeleria\Views\CRUD\editar\editarproducto.view.php:64
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\papeleria\Views\CRUD\editar\editarproducto.view.php(64):
> mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'SELECT p.id_pro...') #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\papeleria\Views\CRUD\editar\editarproducto.view.php on
> line 72

Ese lo solucioné cambiando la variable que tenía por un número entero, pero luego me marca el mismo error, solo que esta vez en la línea 64.

La parte de la función en la que está marcando el error es esta

```
if(empty($_GET['id']))
{
    header('location:/papeleria/views/inventario/listadeinventario.view.php');
}
$idproducto = $_GET['id']; //Esta es la variable que no me deja agregar
                   //El segundo error lo muestra en esta línea, justo donde inicia la sentencia sql
$sql = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT p.id_producto_, (p.clase_id_) AS id_clase, (c.nombre_clase_) AS clase_, (p.subclase_id_) AS id_subclase, (s.nombre_subclase_) AS subc_, (p.marca) AS id_marca_, (m.nombre_marca) AS marcas_, p.descripción_, p.presentación_, p.fecha_ingreso_, p.stock_mínimo_, p.stock_máximo, p.costo_u_c_, p.costo_neto, p.iva_, p.retefuente_, p.valor_compra_
                                FROM productos_ p 
                                INNER JOIN clase_de_producto_ c 
                                subclase_ s 
                                marca_ m
                                ON p.clase_id_ = c.id_clase_ 
                                p.subclase_id_ = s.id_subclase_ 
                                p.marca_ = m.id_marca_
                                WHERE id_producto_= 6"); //Aquí es donde me marca error al poner la variable
$result_sql = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
```

La verdad no sé cuál es el error que tengo, o si me falta agregar algo. Ya intenté separar la sentencia por partes, pero sigue marcando el error en la línea 64.

Adiciono las tablas en cuestión con sus respectivas columnas y relaciones

[image: Tablas y relaciones]

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda <3

Actualizo la situación:

Al ejecutar la consulta en la consola me marcaba que *ya se encontró anteriormente un alias* cerca de sc_ s y marca_ m, que estaban en el mismo INNER JOIN que clase_de_producto_ c. Por lo que puse cada uno en un INNER JOIN diferente, (no sé que tan correcto sea eso, pero así dejó de marcarme ese error).

Luego de corregir eso, ejecuto de nuevo la consulta, pero esta vez me sale

> #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'p.subclase_id_ = s.id_subclase_ p.marca...' en la linea 7

Esta vez ahora necesito saber dónde estoy fallando, esta es la consulta luego de las correcciones

SELECT p.id_producto_, (p.clase_id_) AS id_clase, (c.nombre_clase_) AS clase_, (p.subclase_id_) AS id_subclase, (s.nombre_subclase_) AS subc_, (p.marca) AS id_marca_, (m.nombre_marca) AS marcas_, p.descripcion_, p.presentacion_, p.fecha_ingreso_, p.stock_minimo_, p.stock_maximo, p.costo_u_c_, p.costo_neto, p.iva_, p.retefuente_, p.valor_compra_

FROM productos_ p

INNER JOIN clase_de_producto_ c

INNER JOIN sc_ s

INNER JOIN marca_ m

ON p.clase_id_ = c.id_clase_

p.subclase_id_ = s.id_subclase_ //esta sería la línea 7

p.marca_ = m.id_marca_

WHERE id_producto_= 1

Comment: Prueba tu consulta directamente en el SGBD y revisa qué error imprime, sin conocer tus tablas/columnas difícilmente podremos decirte dónde está el error de sintaxis en la consulta. Si no tienes acceso fácil a SGBD o no sabes, puedes mostrar el error desde el código con algo así: `if($sql) { $result_sql = mysqli_num_rows($sql); } else { printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($conexion)); }` Esto sólo para depuración, en producción no conviene mostrar mensajes de error del SGBD.

Comment: Por favor, revisá la sintaxis de MySQL (no por nada te lanza error de sintaxis). Antes te faltaban las comas en el INNER JOIN, ahora te faltan los AND. Es más, no solo revises la sintaxis de MySQL, sino también la sintaxis del estándar SQL.

Comment: Gracias @padaleiana, al final tenía que poner un ON luego de cada INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero, te sugeriría que pruebes a realizar esa consulta desde el cmd o powershell accediendo a la terminal de MariaDB. Algún error te está dando en la consulta. En base a eso, te tocaría comprobar que todo está escrito correctamente.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.